# Do "interface" and "class" mean the same in duck typing of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I saw uses of "interface" from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document (and other webpages on the same site):

> The Document **interface** represents any web page loaded in the browser and serves as an entry point into the web page's content, which is the DOM tree.

I saw uses of "class" from JavaScript: The Definitive Guide

> Note that the figure contains three different types of nodes. At the root of the tree is the Document node that represents the entire document. The nodes that represent HTML elements are Element nodes, and the nodes that represent text are Text nodes. Document, Element, and Text are **subclasses** of Node and have their own entries in the reference section. Document and Element are the two most important **DOM classes**, and much of this chapter is devoted to their properties and methods. Node and its subtypes form the type hierarchy illustrated in Figure 15-2.
>
> [image]

Comment: The DOM standard(s) use the word `interface` (from [Web IDL](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/) when discussing those "things". See e.g. [`Document`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-document). JavaScript doesn't have the idea of interfaces, so it wouldn't make sense to use that keyword.

Comment: Hi Tim. Your other post was flagged for moderators - I think it would be best if we  do not go down that road. I have opened up a chat with you before, but I do not recall hearing from you. Please open a new one with me if you want some feedback about your membership here - I am worried you are trying to crash and burn deliberately, and I do not think that will be a fruitful outcome for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology from MDN is likely coming from official web specifications which use a [very specific meaning of interface](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl) not related to JavaScript but instead related to writing specifications. From that document:

> This document defines an interface definition language, Web IDL, that
>   can be used to describe interfaces that are intended to be implemented
>   in web browsers. Web IDL is an IDL variant with a number of features
>   that allow the behavior of common script objects in the web platform
>   to be specified more readily. How interfaces described with Web IDL
>   correspond to constructs within ECMAScript execution environments is
>   also detailed in this document.

The section on how to convert specification interfaces to JavaScript is very dense.

As far as JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, I'm pretty sure that's just abusing the word 'class' to mean inheritance. I have that book and will take a closer look at that section to see if I can give a better answer about that.

EDIT: My edition of that book is WAY out of date. I would need to see more context to understand if the author is really talking about JavaScript classes (which do exist as syntactic sugar over prototypical inheritance) or just inheritance. In the end, it doesn't hugely matter since classes just use prototypical inheritance underneath.

Comment: Thanks. Do "interface" and "class" from the two sources mean the same?

Comment: Very likely. I might have doubts if The Definitive Guide were discussing something else, but since he is discussing HTMLDocument being a "subclass" of Document, it's the same thing as MDN is describing. Neither of which are describing something that exists in JavaScript but instead something that is more abstract and refers to whether or not something implements the specification. "Interface" in this case is related just to the specification.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM types are defined in terms of interfaces, not classes. So strictly speaking it is incorrect to call them classes and talk about a class hierarchy. But there is no practical difference for JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. Do "interface" and "class" from the two sources mean the same?

Comment: Yeah. Although "interface" is technically more correct, there is no practical difference to JavaScript. I would guess the author uses "class" for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

## DOM

Documentation from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) regarding [the DOM and other APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) generally take their language from the standards they reference. For instance [MDN's page on `Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) refers to, among others, [WHATWG's Living Standard for the DOM](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-document).

My understanding is that, because the WHATWG (and W3C) do not make any suggestions as to *how* user agents implement those interfaces, calling them anything else would be misleading.

It should be noted that MDN is not necessarily consistent. MDN refers to `Element` as:

> ... the most general base class from which all objects in a Document inherit. It only has methods and properties common to all kinds of elements. More specific classes inherit from Element. For example, the HTMLElement interface is the base interface for HTML elements, while the SVGElement interface is the basis for all SVG elements. Most functionality is specified further down the class hierarchy.

Whereas `Node` is referred to as:

> ...an interface from which a number of DOM API object types inherit. It allows those types to be treated similarly; for example, inheriting the same set of methods, or being tested in the same way.

Technically, it's more accurate to refer to them as interfaces when discussing the DOM.

## JavaScript

JavaScript and its parent standard, ECMAScript, does not have an idea of user-creatable interfaces. The only place the ECMAScript standard references the word "interface" is in [the section on Iteration](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-iteration) (and later in the section on Generators, since they reference those Iteration interfaces).

## Betwixt the two lies madness

It's where the two meet that the confusion starts. JavaScript engines (like those in browsers) *implement* the interfaces defined in the DOM. So they may very well use classes for that implementation. They should be able to be used interchangeably, but not always. For instance, a bug in, say, Internet Explorer's implementation of a DOM interface should likely talk about classes.

Your title mentions duck typing, so it bears mentioning that browsers may prevent alteration of DOM-related classes for extension.